# Update to 3.6.3: hitting php memory limit

Tags: php, update

I'm trying to update my installed Joomla! 3.6.2 to 3.6.3 using the update tool provided. On doing so I seem to hit the php Memory limit:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8912897 bytes) in /$PATH/www/libraries/joomla/utilities/buffer.php on line 104
```

I'm hosting on a shared hoster (all-inkl.com) and tried to increase Memory limit by putting `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` into my index.php an /administrator/index.php. Both did not seem to change anything.

I tried updating as described in the [joomla doc](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_Joomla_(Install_Method)) but *Install from URL* and *Upload a Package* also run into the memory limit.
The *Install from directory* method complains that "Path leeds to invalid packet" ("Der Pfad führt zu keinem gültigen Paket!") and "Warning: Joomla! Packet cannot be installed like an extension, please use update component." ("Das Joomla!-Paket kann nicht wie andere Erweiterungen installiert werden. Hierfür muss die Joomla!-Aktualisierungskomponente genutzt werden.")

Which other updating option do I have?

Comment: Check [this manual](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5). altough it says update to 3.5 but you can choose any method in that document to update to 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cwps](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/2247/cwps) posted this comment:

> Check [this manual](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5). altough it says update to 3.5 but you can choose any method in that document to update to 3.6.3

Method C worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of" you can ask your hosting to increase these values from the php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
```

( source: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/allowed-memory-size-exausted )

Comment: thank you, but I don't think my webhoster is flexible enough to do that.